# How to add a seed to pseudorandom number generator?

Tags: java, random-seed

I am currently working on an assignment with creating three heads in a row and I got it working but I am failing the tester assigned to me because it's saying my random number generator needs to take a seed parameter for this particular problem.  My code for this is :

```
public static void threeHeads() {
        Random r = new Random();
        //int seed = r.nextInt();
        int head =0;
        while (head!=3) {
            Boolean random = r.nextBoolean();
            
            if(random==false) {
                System.out.print("H");
                head++;
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("T");
                head=0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nThree heads in a row!");
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The random constructor is overloaded with a method: `Random(long seed)`, which allows you to instantiate a random number generator with a preset seed.